# Trigger.io -- Facebook app install tracking

Tags: android, ios, facebook, tracking, trigger.io

I've created an iOS and Android app using Trigger.io, and am using Trigger's Facebook module to enable user signups. Furthermore, I've created a Facebook app to link Facebook ads to mobile app installations in both iTunes and Google Play. I would like to be able to track these installations from FB ads.

Documentation for doing this on native apps is found in the links below:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/measurement/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/#advanced

... however, I'm running into issues with Trigger. As I cannot include any custom code to register the installation of the app with FB, I'm not sure if there's any way to achieve the same result with Trigger. As is, the current Trigger Facebook module doesn't appear to be registering any app installs, even with test accounts.

Hopefully I haven't missed anything obvious... any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Trigger facebook module doesn't currently track installs as described in the documentation you linked.

However Trigger is planning on open sourcing the code for the facebook module shortly, which would allow you to include the custom code required and include your own slightly modified version of the module in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. So, if I wanted to create a custom module (as in https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/index.html), would that allow me to leverage the Facebook SDK (and/or Google SDK to track adwords conversion) to invoke their native app tracking API call?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger.io fixed this issue in version 2.8 of the Facebook module, and it now calls AppEventsLogger.activateApp() with the facebook ID.